# popup windows and AnimationSet vs AnimationStyle

Tags: java, android

After successfully experimenting with getting Layouts to animate by creating AnimationSet's programmatically, I wanted to try the same thing with popup windows. Unfortunately it appears that popup windows can only have their animations controlled by setting AnimationStyles (which I know can be defined in xml), but is there any way of programmatically arranging animations for popup windows? Is there some sort of AnimationSet to AnimationStyle conversion?

An explanation of the difference between an AnimationSet and an AnimationStyle would be a bonus.